# Why quots encoded in JSON in razor view page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I am newer in web programming and in asp.net mvc4, so maybe my question will seem naive to some of you.
I am passing JSON with help of @ViewBag.

I parse JSON in razor view page using this rows:

```
var strJson = '@ViewBag.Json';  
var strDecoded = strJson.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'); 
var JSONParsed = strDecoded.parse();
```

Here is row in my controller class that creates JSON:

```
ViewBag.Json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(contacts);
```

Evrething works fine,my question about this row:

```
strJson.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
```

Before I sent the JSON to the razor view page I see quots not encoded,
but in JSON in razor view page I see quots encoded(").

Why I get quots encoded in JSON in razor view page?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Razor autmatically HTML-encodes all text that you output.
You can prevent this by calling `Html.Raw()`.

Also, JSON is already valid Javascript; there is no need to parse a string:

```
var jsonParsed = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Json);
```